# Disable serial console of raspberry pi

Tags: python, serial-port, raspberry-pi

I follow the guide in this site http://elinux.org/RPi_Serial_Connection to disable linux from using serial port, but it's clearly that this will also prevent me from log in to Raspberry Pi by using Minicom. How can I access Raspberry Pi via Minicom to work? 
I am trying to transmit data from RaspberryPi to Linux PC but it doesn't work. I thought disable serial port is a solution but it causes another problem for me to log in and run script. 
Help me please???

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell

Comment: yeah, I already use Putty to connect to RaspberryPi computer, but to do that, i have to using minicom to configure ip addr and netmask, without loging in, how can i configure RaspberryPi to open with Putty ?

Answer (score 0):

There are several options:

1) Connect a monitor and keyboard to the Raspberry Pi and log in that way.

2) configure a fixed IP and other network configuration before disabling the serial port login

3) use a DHCP server to automatically assign a network configuration to the Pi. DHCP can be configured to assigned a fixed address, or you can check its tables to see what address it has assigned to the Pi each time you boot it.

Edit to add:
4) disabling serial port login doesn't have to be permanent. Leave serial port login enabled when the Pi boots, but have your script turn it off as it starts and maybe turn it back on when it's done.